# html to text in excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to convert HTML in excel cells to plain text. For example, I have this in cell C18:

```
<p><b>ORGANIC LIP BALM </b></p><p><b>Peppermint</b></p>
```

The output in D18 should be:
ORGANIC LIP BALM Peppermint

Looking for a VBA macro to do the conversion. The HTML itself is located within the cells of a column. So for example, rows 1-100 in column C have HTML in them, which I want to convert to plain text in column D.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have to be more specific if you want somebody to help you. Are you trying to write a macro in VBA? Where are you reading the HTML from? How are you reading it? Also, it helps a lot if you show the piece of code that's doing the job.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will update now.